# Everyplay records video, but crashes when i tap on "Share" and "View profile"

Tags: everyplay

I am using everyplay to record my game play, and players can share the video at the result screen.

The recording, sharing and viewing of profile on the iPad is working fine, but every iPhone build (4, 4S, 5) will crash when I tap on the "share", "view everyplay profile" button at the Everyplay page.

We tracked what is happening when we tapped on those 2 buttons.

```
2013-08-01 10:29:19.489 ZombieBlackout[6602:907] Video Updated
2013-08-01 10:29:20.786 ZombieBlackout[6602:907] everyplayRecordingStopped
2013-08-01 10:29:20.788 ZombieBlackout[6602:907] everyplayShown
2013-08-01 10:29:22.393 ZombieBlackout[6602:907] Audio route change while recording was stopped.
2013-08-01 10:29:22.394 ZombieBlackout[6602:907] A route change occurred that does not require stopping application audio.
2013-08-01 10:29:22.451 ZombieBlackout[6602:907] Audio route change while recording was stopped.
2013-08-01 10:29:22.453 ZombieBlackout[6602:907] A route change occurred that does not require stopping application audio.
2013-08-01 10:29:27.488 ZombieBlackout[6602:907] Video Updated
2013-08-01 10:29:35.383 ZombieBlackout[6602:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3304f3e7 0x3ad40963 0x3304f307 0x34ec688f 0x3506b0c9 0x3f388d 0x3f0dad 0x3e1e5b 0x3e1d4b 0x3b15a793 0x3b15a5db 0x3b15de45 0x330231b1 0x32f9623d 0x32f960c9 0x36b7433b 0x34eb22b9 0xb1503 0xb02b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

And I don't think it is because our build is on the iPhone, because I tried Nimble Quest on iPhone and I am able to tap on the stated 2 buttons.

I am using Cocos2dx, the way we code is ready for Android. I am wondering if there is a problem with cocos2dx with Everyplay.

Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I assume your game is landscape only. In that case you have two options how to fix this.

Option 1:

Add UISupportedInterfaceOrientations array into your game's info.plist with items UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait, UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight and UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown. You can easily do this from xCode by checking all Supported Interface Orientations from your project summary page or by editing the info.plist file manually.

Option 2:

Add the following method to your application's AppDelegate.m file:

```
// IOS 6

-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

In both cases you must also make sure that you have added the landscape only orientation handling code to your game's UIViewController.

```
// IOS 5

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

// IOS 6

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
   return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```